# Websites with javascript application examples

Tags: javascript

I've been learning Javascript for two months now and I've noticed I learn a lot by looking at code of other people. Is there a website with a lot of examples of applications of javascript code (preferably with a beginner's section)?

Comment: Codecademy is perfect for showing you the capability of JavaScript. Github is perfect for showing you what people have built with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd check out **[this Github search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language%3AJavaScript&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=JavaScript&l=)** for tons of projects using javascript.

Otherwise there's W3Schools with a lot of quick and easy javascript tutorials and code examples for beginners.
Here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp